# Error in x[, ii] : subscript out of bounds with plm package

Tags: r, panel-data, plm, economics

Whilst running the following line of code:

```
Pfit1 = plm(hits ~ countDir, data = Pdf1, model = "within" , effect = "twoways")
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in x[, ii] : subscript out of bounds
```

However, I do not know where to go from here as I am unable to discover what is going wrong here, based on this error.

DataFrame:

```
dput(Pfit1)
```

structure(list(hits = c(2L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 30L, 11L, 10L, 17L, 29L, 
100L, 80L, 36L, 24L, 15L, 18L, 16L, 16L, 13L, 11L, 6L, 8L, 9L, 
8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 5L, 13L, 10L, 14L, 7L, 13L, 18L, 13L, 13L, 17L, 
23L, 79L, 66L, 41L, 53L, 40L, 53L, 26L, 20L, 25L, 22L, 15L, 14L, 
10L, 15L, 21L, 14L, 11L, 14L, 9L, 9L, 8L, 11L, 8L, 11L, 15L, 
9L, 5L, 8L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 8L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 8L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 
20L, 9L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 
5L, 12L, 12L, 9L, 20L, 77L, 53L, 77L, 91L, 80L, 73L, 74L, 81L, 
65L, 55L, 56L, 54L, 51L, 45L, 47L, 47L, 48L, 100L, 72L, 84L, 
97L, 72L, 55L, 46L, 40L, 39L, 34L, 35L, 26L, 24L, 24L, 20L, 20L, 
21L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 16L, 19L, 18L), countDir = c(492, 492, 492, 
492, 492, 492, 492, 492, 492, 492, 492, 492, 492, 492, 492, 492, 
492, 492, 492, 492, 492, 492, 492, 492, 492, 492, 492, 492, 492, 
492, 492, 492, 492, 492, 492, 492, 492, 492, 492, 492, 492, 492, 
492, 492, 492, 492, 492, 492, 492, 492, 492, 492, 492, 492, 492, 
492, 492, 492, 492, 492, 492, 492, 492, 492, 492, 492, 492, 492, 
492, 417, 417, 417, 417, 417, 417, 417, 417, 417, 417, 417, 417, 
417, 417, 417, 417, 417, 417, 417, 417, 417, 417, 417, 417, 417, 
417, 417, 417, 417, 417, 417, 417, 417, 417, 417, 417, 417, 417, 
417, 417, 417, 417, 417, 417, 417, 417, 417, 417, 417, 417, 417, 
417, 417, 417, 417, 417, 417, 417, 417, 417, 417, 417, 417, 417, 
417, 417, 417, 417, 417), countAct = c(68, 68, 68, 68, 68, 68, 
68, 68, 68, 68, 68, 68, 68, 68, 68, 68, 68, 68, 68, 68, 68, 68, 
68, 68, 68, 68, 68, 68, 68, 68, 68, 68, 68, 68, 68, 68, 68, 68, 
68, 68, 68, 68, 68, 68, 68, 68, 68, 68, 68, 68, 68, 68, 68, 68, 
68, 68, 68, 68, 68, 68, 68, 68, 68, 68, 68, 68, 68, 68, 68, 354, 
354, 354, 354, 354, 354, 354, 354, 354, 354, 354, 354, 354, 354, 
354, 354, 354, 354, 354, 354, 354, 354, 354, 354, 354, 354, 354, 
354, 354, 354, 354, 354, 354, 354, 354, 354, 354, 354, 354, 354, 
354, 354, 354, 354, 354, 354, 354, 354, 354, 354, 354, 354, 354, 
354, 354, 354, 354, 354, 354, 354, 354, 354, 354, 354, 354, 354, 
354, 354, 354), ReleaseBetween = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1), Genre = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L), .Label = c(" Biography", " Drama"), class = "factor"), 
    year = c(2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 
    2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 
    2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 
    2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 
    2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 
    2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 
    2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 
    2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2008L, 
    2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 
    2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 
    2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 
    2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 
    2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 
    2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 
    2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 
    2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L), period = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
    3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
    3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
    3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 
    2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
    3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
    3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
    3)), .Names = c("hits", "countDir", "countAct", "ReleaseBetween", 
"Genre", "year", "period"), class = c("pdata.frame", "data.frame"
), row.names = c("Adieu au langage--9", "Adieu au langage--8", 
"Adieu au langage--7", "Adieu au langage--6", "Adieu au langage--5", 
"Adieu au langage--4", "Adieu au langage--3", "Adieu au langage--2", 
"Adieu au langage--1", "Adieu au langage-0", "Adieu au langage-1", 
"Adieu au langage-2", "Adieu au langage-3", "Adieu au langage-4", 
"Adieu au langage-5", "Adieu au langage-6", "Adieu au langage-7", 
"Adieu au langage-8", "Adieu au langage-9", "Adieu au langage-10", 
"Adieu au langage-11", "Adieu au langage-12", "Adieu au langage-13", 
"Adieu au langage-14", "Adieu au langage-15", "Adieu au langage-16", 
"Adieu au langage-17", "Adieu au langage-18", "Adieu au langage-19", 
"Adieu au langage-20", "Adieu au langage-21", "Adieu au langage-22", 
"Adieu au langage-23", "Adieu au langage-24", "Adieu au langage-25", 
"Adieu au langage-26", "Adieu au langage-27", "Adieu au langage-28", 
"Adieu au langage-29", "Adieu au langage-30", "Adieu au langage-31", 
"Adieu au langage-32", "Adieu au langage-33", "Adieu au langage-34", 
"Adieu au langage-35", "Adieu au langage-36", "Adieu au langage-37", 
"Adieu au langage-38", "Adieu au langage-39", "Adieu au langage-40", 
"Adieu au langage-41", "Adieu au langage-42", "Adieu au langage-43", 
"Adieu au langage-44", "Adieu au langage-45", "Adieu au langage-46", 
"Adieu au langage-47", "Adieu au langage-48", "Adieu au langage-49", 
"Adieu au langage-50", "Adieu au langage-51", "Adieu au langage-52", 
"Adieu au langage-53", "Adieu au langage-54", "Adieu au langage-55", 
"Adieu au langage-56", "Adieu au langage-57", "Adieu au langage-58", 
"Adieu au langage-59", "Changeling--9", "Changeling--8", "Changeling--7", 
"Changeling--6", "Changeling--5", "Changeling--4", "Changeling--3", 
"Changeling--2", "Changeling--1", "Changeling-0", "Changeling-1", 
"Changeling-2", "Changeling-3", "Changeling-4", "Changeling-5", 
"Changeling-6", "Changeling-7", "Changeling-8", "Changeling-9", 
"Changeling-10", "Changeling-11", "Changeling-12", "Changeling-13", 
"Changeling-14", "Changeling-15", "Changeling-16", "Changeling-17", 
"Changeling-18", "Changeling-19", "Changeling-20", "Changeling-21", 
"Changeling-22", "Changeling-23", "Changeling-24", "Changeling-25", 
"Changeling-26", "Changeling-27", "Changeling-28", "Changeling-29", 
"Changeling-30", "Changeling-31", "Changeling-32", "Changeling-33", 
"Changeling-34", "Changeling-35", "Changeling-36", "Changeling-37", 
"Changeling-38", "Changeling-39", "Changeling-40", "Changeling-41", 
"Changeling-42", "Changeling-43", "Changeling-44", "Changeling-45", 
"Changeling-46", "Changeling-47", "Changeling-48", "Changeling-49", 
"Changeling-50", "Changeling-51", "Changeling-52", "Changeling-53", 
"Changeling-54", "Changeling-55", "Changeling-56", "Changeling-57", 
"Changeling-58", "Changeling-59"), index = structure(list(keyword = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Adieu au langage", 
"Changeling"), class = "factor"), date = structure(c(1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 
17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 
30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 
43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 
56L, 57L, 58L, 59L, 60L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 64L, 65L, 66L, 67L, 68L, 
69L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 
14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 
27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 
40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 
53L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 59L, 60L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 64L, 65L, 
66L, 67L, 68L, 69L), .Label = c("-9", "-8", "-7", "-6", "-5", 
"-4", "-3", "-2", "-1", "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", 
"8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", 
"19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", 
"30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "40", 
"41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47", "48", "49", "50", "51", 
"52", "53", "54", "55", "56", "57", "58", "59"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("keyword", 
"date"), class = c("pindex", "data.frame"), row.names = c("110101", 
"210101", "310101", "410101", "510101", "610101", "71681", "81681", 
"91681", "101681", "112071", "121841", "131711", "141681", "151681", 
"161681", "171681", "181681", "191681", "201681", "212081", "221841", 
"231711", "241681", "251681", "261681", "271681", "281681", "291681", 
"301681", "312071", "321841", "331711", "341681", "351681", "361681", 
"371681", "381681", "391681", "401681", "412071", "421841", "431711", 
"441681", "451681", "461681", "471681", "481681", "491681", "501681", 
"512071", "521841", "531711", "541681", "551681", "561681", "571681", 
"581681", "591681", "601681", "612071", "621841", "631711", "641681", 
"651681", "661681", "671681", "681681", "691681", "12031", "22031", 
"32031", "42031", "52031", "62031", "7641", "8641", "9641", "10641", 
"111031", "12661", "13641", "14641", "15641", "16641", "17641", 
"18641", "19641", "20641", "211041", "22661", "23641", "24641", 
"25641", "26641", "27641", "28641", "29641", "30641", "311031", 
"32661", "33641", "34641", "35641", "36641", "37641", "38641", 
"39641", "40641", "411031", "42661", "43641", "44641", "45641", 
"46641", "47641", "48641", "49641", "50641", "511031", "52661", 
"53641", "54641", "55641", "56641", "57641", "58641", "59641", 
"60641", "611031", "62661", "63641", "64641", "65641", "66641", 
"67641", "68641", "69641")))

Answer (score 1):

This is specific to your data/a statistical problem: there is no time variation per individual in your variable `countDir` and thus, your within model is not estimable.

you can run `pvar(Pdf1)` to see that:

```
no time variation:       countDir countAct ReleaseBetween Genre year 
no individual variation: period
```

plm's error message could be improved, though.